# Как создается диск в оперативной памяти?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте! 
Необходимо чтобы часть оперативной памяти определялась как жесткий диск. Знаю о существовании такой утилиты как Dataram RAMDisk, но хотелось бы это сделать "в ручную". То есть написать какой то код допустим на С++ чтобы он делал эту операцию. Может можно где достать исходники этой программы или кто то знает как это можно написать на С++? ОС - Windows.

Comment: ОС укажите хотя бы...

Comment: Вам нужно написать драйвер. Начните со скачивания DDK что ли.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Рассказать как ЭТО написать на c++ в рамках ответа не получится. Действительно речь идет о разработке драйвера, а это вещь очень непростая.

А вот по поводу исходников такой программы - все очень просто:

1. Даем гуглу запрос "windows memory disk open source".
2. В ответе самая первая ссылка идет уже очень интересная https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RAM_drive_software
3. Там прямо в оглавлении есть например такой пункт "Ramdisk.sys sample driver for Windows 2000"
4. Скачивайте, изучайте